# Render local tiles as <TileLayer> in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

When I run my local .png tile library in a simple Leaflet index.html I get perfectly rendered and geo-correct tiles:

```
    <script>
        function onLoad() {

            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([-42.132, 147.175], 12);

            L.tileLayer('demo-map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            {    maxZoom: 16  }).addTo(mymap);
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();"> 
    <div id="mapid" style="height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

But when I put the same path in "url=" in react-leaflet TileLayer, the tiles do not render.

```
          <BaseLayer checked name="Local Map (Offline)">
        <TileLayer
          attribution="This map is offline"
          url="demo-map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </BaseLayer>
```

The .png tiles are stored in src/demo-map/ in the same directory structure that Mobile Atlas Creator exported

Can anyone help me load my tiles in react-leaflet, or suggest a method incorporating standard Leaflet into my React app, bypassing react-leaflet and TileLayer?

Thank you

Comment: Is your browser requesting any tiles? Use the network tab of your web browser's developer tools.

Comment: @IvanSanchez thanks. Yes I didn't think to check as it's local but the tiles are being requested, but not rendered. Here are the details: Request URL: http://localhost:3000/demo-map/12/3721/2576.png Request Method: GET Status Code: 304 Not Modified Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Then make sure that your webserver at localhost:3000 is serving the tiles.

Comment: @IvanSanchez this is solved - silly mistake, I had the map tiles in the /src directory. Moving the tiles folder to the /public directory of my app solved the problem. Thanks for leading me to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

what worked for me, is that i moved my tiles folder into the public directory, then in the jsx code I refer to it like this :
[image: code]

and this is my directory :
[image: public directory]